# Can bookmarking a page test DNS change?

Tags: bookmarks, google-dns

I tried the google DNS and I actually get faster speed however in their testing section they [state](https://developers.google.com/speed/public-dns/docs/using#testing):
Navigate to google.come and bookmark it, if works both times you are set.

Why isn't the first test enough? We are getting a web page so surely DNS is configured correctly isn't it?

Answer (score 0):

That does appear to be weird advice from Google.   If you go to the site and it works, DNS is probably working.  (It might not if its cached, but bookmarking it won't fix that).

Answer (score 0):

Those steps are testing if Google's resolver and your resolver are "seeing" the same information.  If you hover your mouse of the bookmark and check your status bar, you should see that the link actually points to Google.  Notice that the step 3 of the test has you using your own DNS server.

If you can visit the page using Google's DNS but can't with your own, then you have local issues to troubleshoot.  If you can visit the page using your own server but not with Google's DNS, then your DNS records are not making out onto the Internet (e.g., could be caused by your registrar not pointing at your DNS server).